# MySQL events and timing

Tags: mysql, events

I have created event in mysql that should run every day but one thing is not clear to me...

For example, if I set to run every day but without specifiying start date-time when it will event occure? In what time?

If I have event like this:

```
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-11-27 00:00:05'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
```

Does it mean that this event will fire each day at 00:00:05?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It will run forever at Specified time and with interval of one day. Yes it will be on 00:00:05 database server time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would start daily at 00:00:05

Like, event to run every month, starting at some date in the future at 1 o’clock in the morning, you would use the following:

```
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH
    STARTS '2011-12-01 01:00:00'
```

[Reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-mysql-events/)